# DHCP reservations by hostname and router lease

Tags: networking, dhcp, hostname

I'm French sorry if the wording is not perfect.

To give you a little context, I don't have any diploma in IT but I joined my colleague in the IT department of our company. He's been dealing with this for years. He set this up when there were only a few PCs. today There are around 80 pcs. We only have Windows as OS

Currently most PCs have a fixed IP in the 192.10.10.x range. There is also a part of this range reserved for dhcp. There are also some dhcp reservations for laptops which are used to configure industrial machines (the operator need to change the parameters of the network card) but which we want them to have fixed IPs when they are on the LAN.

I see two problems with this:

- anyone who physically connects to one of our sockets can go on the internet (even without dhcp, by knowing the gateway's IP)
- it is very easy to make a mistake and put the same IP twice on two PCs

So I would like to know how this works in companies of comparable size. are you using captive portals or something like that?

---

On another matter, I found this answer very interesting:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405220

```
You can have a DHCP server that identifies machines by hostname. Then if you change the network card and therefore the MAC address, it will still get the same IP.
```

So my idea was the following: I get a new PC (for a new arrival for example), I give it a hostname, for example its service tag, but keep it in DHCP. Then I go to the dhcp server to tell it that this hostname will appear on the LAN and that when that happens it must give it an IP and make a reservation for it. And in the same time, the dhcp server sends the MAC to the router to tell it to offer that MAC an access toward the outside.
So after that, if someone comes with an unknown PC and copies a hostname or whatever, they won't be able to access the internet.

Does anyone use such a system?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> anyone who physically connects to one of our sockets can go on the internet (even without dhcp, by knowing the gateway's IP)

[802.1x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X). Authenticate who can connect to your network. Anything else is basically not security, but polite requests.

> it is very easy to make a mistake and put the same IP twice on two PCs

Use DHCP. If anything requires fixed IP's use DHCP reservations.

Comment: Ok thks. So if I understand correctly the new device is blocked at the switch entrance and therefore cannot communicate with anything until it identified itself. How is this authentication made in the majority of medium-sized companies? Through a captive portal or with Xsupplicant /  wpa_supplicant as described in your link ?

Comment: The authentication is typically handled by the operating system. As you only have Windows, Active Directory or Entra ID would be the obvious choice.